# loop not functioning properly

Tags: php, loops

I am unable to get this loop to function properly. Whenever `($records[$row][2] == $prevRow2)` I need it to recreate the class=field and only close the div=row that's part of the group where `($records[$row][2] == $prevRow2)`.  Please help!!

```
    if (($handle = fopen('upload/ATLANTA.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $prevRow2 = false;
                $row=0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {
            $num = count($data);
            $records[] = $data;
            echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>";
            echo 'Is '. $prevRow2 . 'the same as ' .$records[$row][2];

            if ($records[$row][2] == $prevRow2) {
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                if ($c != 1) {
                    echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
                    }   
                }

                $prevRow2 = $records[$row][2];
                $row++;
                echo "<div id=\"filler\"></div>";

            }//if close

            else {
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    if ($c != 1) {  
                    echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
                    }   
                }
                $prevRow2 = $records[$row][2];
                $row++;
            }//close else           
        echo '</div>';
        }//close while

fclose($handle);
```

}

Comment: You should clean up your code and indent it accordingly, hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$row seems to be null until the line you make $row++;

Comment: That has not stopped it from looping.

Comment: Maybe not but PHP is very permissive. You should set $row=0; before entering into your loop while

Answer (score 0):

Some output and/or further description of your data would really help, but  I notice a few things.

1 - Your closing if and else do exactly the same thing except for this filler div.  I get the impression this is not what you desire, but I don't really understand enough to suggest what to do.

> ```
>             for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
>             if ($c != 1) {
>                 echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
>                 }   
>             }
>             $prevRow2 = $records[$row][2];
>             $row++;
> ```

This code is common to both the if and else blocks, so it executes no matter what.  Is that what you want?  If so, you might as well move it out of the if and move only the filler div into the if, nothing in the else.

2 - What is the purpose of $records and $records[$row].  As far as I can see, $records[$row] === $data whenever its used.

3 - The div with id=row is closed at the end of every while loop.  You seem to suggest you don't want this, put if you only do it when $records[$row][2] AKA $data[2] matches the previous iteration's, I don't think your HTML will be well formed.

4 - try using foreach instead of your foor loops

Comment: Thank you for responding.  

The file that I am using to run the function on looks like this:
603405,0,V0123,"CompanyA",4547.67,10/01/2010,4547.67
603441,0,V0178,"CompanyB",15.96,10/01/2010,15.96
603383,0,V0223,"CompanyC",1139.05,10/01/2010,1139.05
603431,1,V0223,"CompanyC",275.50,10/01/2010,275.50

I am looking to print a row based on each line in the file, and if the company name repeats then I'd like for it to be part of the same row.

Comment: Actually I'll post a new one.  You might want to consider the form suggestions on this one here, but the new answer should solve things.

Comment: Where can I find the new post? And where are the form suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Company is actually index 3, not 2.

> ```
>     $prevData3 = false;
>     $row=0;
>     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {
>         if ($data[2] != $prevData2)
>         {
>             if ($prevData2) echo '</div>';
>             echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>";
>             row++;
>          }
>              else echo "<div id=\"filler\"></div>";
>         foreach ($data as $d) {
>             if ($c != 1) {
>                 echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $d . "</div>";
>             }
>         }
>              echo "<br />";
>         $prevData2 = $data[2];
>     }
> ```
>
> echo CLOSE_DIV;

Comment: I was having a hard time putting in the tag at the end, so replace CLOSE_DIV with you-know-what

Comment: Your use of $records was unnecessary, so I took it out.  the for loops are replaced with foreach, which is equivalent and works pretty similar.  if this is a new company: output close div as long as this isnt the first time, output open div id=row.  output all fields no matter what.  if this is not a new company, output div with id=filler.  end while.  close the hanging div.

Comment: This is almost working...  But not quite.  Its closing the <div id=row> at the end of every row while I need all rows that have the same company name to be inside one row. And the close row div should print at the end.

Comment: This is what it outputs right now.. http://www.ideahoppers.com/cchnet/SAP_TEST.php

Comment: ok, i guess the index of data actually should be 2.  search and replace [3] to [2].  see whatever is responsible for '</div' without the finishing '>' and fix it, its not like that in the code i gave you.  also put a <br /> right after the foreach so you have some semblance of readability  CHECK OUT THE EDITED ANSWER ABOVE

Comment: Its SO close! Its just not closing <div id=row> in the proper place.